# Why aren't my divs showing up?

Tags: css, html

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title>Some Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 75%;
    background-color: black;
}

#left {
    height: 600px;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: gray;
}

#right {
    height: 600px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.footer {
    height: 100px;
    width: 75%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

http://cssdesk.com/aVCZc

If there is something that oblivious about the code and is completely wrong, can someone point it out to me? The divs aren't showing up for me.

Comment: div's* I accidentally left the < and > marks in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your CSS selectors you have them backwards. `.` is for classes, `#` for ids

Comment: That is one of the dumbest mistakes I've made in a long time... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you simply mis-typed id and class indicators:

class ==> should be .
id ==> should be #